# I have a .dll compiled with various optimization flags using g++, how do I dynamically link it to my application?

Tags: c++, dynamic, dll, linker, mingw

I have a **.dll library** on **Windows** which I compiled using **mingw g++** on the **command line** with various flags to optimize it, but I need to link it to my project so that the **.dll** is required to run the compiled **.exe** (as far as I understand, this is **implicit/dynamic linking**). This is originally a **macOS** project, so I can't figure out how to link it to my **Visual Studio** project since it seems I need a .lib file.

The way I create the **.dll** file is by inputting this command in cmd inside the lib folder :

```
g++ -shared -DNDEBUG -IC:\Users\luis.lopez\Documents\libraries\eigen\ -march=native -ftree-vectorize -ffast-math -fstrict-aliasing -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -fopenmp -o libfoo.dll foolibrary.cpp
```

Is there a way for me to create the **.lib file** while maintaining these compilation flags?

Comment: If you compiled that lib yourself you have access to the source code. Why don't you recompile the DLL with VS?

Comment: I have various optimization flags that are available in the g++ compiler, not sure how I would do that with the VS compiler.

Comment: Type "msvc <option-name>" in Google. You'll find an equivalent for [most](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/o-options-optimize-code) if not all.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `-Wl,--output-def,libfoo.def` to generate `libfoo.def`.
Then you should be able to generate an MSVC `.lib` file, see: [How to generate an import library (LIB-file) from a DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946322/how-to-generate-an-import-library-lib-file-from-a-dll)

But to properly port to Windows you need to make sure the symbols are in fact exported by the library using `__declspec(dllexport)` and imported using `__declspec(dllimport)` by the code using the library, see for example: [linkage between dllimport and dllexport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975578/linkage-between-dllimport-and-dllexport)

Comment: I'm using `-Wl,--out-implib,libcafx_dll.lib` flag and it makes the .lib directly. Is there any benefit to doing a .def first?

Comment: In the method I described you are sure the .lib file is generated by MSVC tools, but that works too.